# Why same thing don't compile correctly in c++

Tags: c++, g++

I can't understand why same thing don't compile correctly(on of them get compile error!)

Here is my function

```cpp
template<long long base, long long power>
constexpr long long pow()
```

When i put

```cpp
return power >= 1 ? base * pow<base, (power - 1)>() : 1;
```

it raise this error:

```
fatal error: template instantiation depth exceeds maximum of 900 (use ‘-ftemplate-depth=’ to increase the maximum)
    5 |     return power >= 1 ? base * pow<base, (power - 1) >() : 1;
      |                                ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~
```

**But** when i put

```cpp
return power >= 1 ? base * pow<base, (power - 1) * (power > 0)>() : 1;
```

It compile successfully!

Comment: What is the value of `power - 1`? What is the value of `power > 0`?

Comment: power is always greeter than 0, Meening `power > 0` is always 1,Also `1 * (power - 1)` is `(power-1)`,But it raise error without `(power > 0)`

Comment: Please provide [mcve] which can be run/compiled. For example use https://godbolt.org/ for that.

Answer (score 2):

When you do `return power >= 1 ? base * pow<base, (power - 1)>() : 1;`, regardless of the result of `power >= 1` comparison, the compiler is forced to instantiate the template, even though it's not called. When you do `pow<base, (power - 1) * (power > 0)>`, it eventually falls back on `0` (since any number times 0 is 0) and doesn't have to generate instantiations for -1, etc. A better way to do that would be to:

```
template<long long base, long long power>
constexpr long long pow() {
  if constexpr (power >= 1) return base * pow<base, (power - 1)>();
  else return 1;
}
```

Here, the compiler is free to (mostly) ignore the pass it's not going to follow.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that for example for `pow<base,power>()` you always intantiate `pow<base,power-1>`. The ternary operator `power>=1` is not evaluated at compile time, it is evaluated at run time. So the compiler needs to instantiate the template `base` and `power-1`. This is like recursion, but without termination. So the compiler will not stop at `pow<base,0>` but continue with `pow<base,-1>` and so on.

Your changed implementation results for `pow<base,0>` in a call to `pow<base, -1*0>`, which is just `pow<base,0>` again and thus no other instantiation of `pow` is needed.

Another solution is to let the compiler do the check at compile time by using `if constexpr`. `if constexpr` has the effect that the code in the chosen will be compiled, but the code in the other path will not be compiled. So for the case `power==0` the compiler only needs to generate code for `return 1;` but not for `return base * pow<base, (power - 1)>();`. So the recursion ends here also at compile time and not only at runtime.

```
template<long long base, long long power>
constexpr long long pow() 
{
    if constexpr(power >= 1)
        return base * pow<base, (power - 1)>();
    else
        return 1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Problem is that most probably your definition of `pow` do to many recursions of itself. To prevent errors compiler limits dept of template definitions and calls of constexpressions and you have exceeded that limit.

To prevent to exceeded this limit you have to correct algorithm to have logarithmic complexity not linear.

```cpp
using ullint = unsigned long long;

template<ullint base, ullint power>
constexpr ullint pow() 
{
    if constexpr(power != 0ll)
        return (power % 2 != 0 ? base : 1) * pow<base * base, power / 2>();
    else
        return 1;
}
```

https://godbolt.org/z/8PvEGE